How to inject custom responseSignatureValidator in Spring Saml2 (using Spring Boot 3 with Spring Security 6.1.x
I'm trying to get past from Spring saml2 validation when receiving a saml response. I would like to verify the response myself. Or if possible let SAML2 decrypt it.
Processing SAML response from https://xyz
2024-09-20T13:23:43.556+03:00  INFO 20992 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] com.example.demo.SecurityConfiguration   : response is not signed, still returning success 
2024-09-20T13:23:43.581+03:00 DEBUG 20992 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] .s.p.s.a.OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider : Found 1 validation errors in SAML response [_168d73f517f1e3e6dd893040172c5c69]: [[invalid_signature] Did not decrypt response [_168d73f517f1e3e6dd893040172c5c69] since it is not signed]
2024-09-20T13:23:43.581+03:00 TRACE 20992 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] .p.s.w.a.Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter : Failed to process authentication request

In the response there is no signature (msg below) used but still saml4 wants to check the signing which fails of course. Response is a custom message where the key to decrypt the actual message is also encrypted. Public key is in the response.
So far I have get past of validation errors by doing this:
private OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider openSaml4AuthenticationProvider() {
        OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider p = new OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider();

        p.setAssertionValidator(source -> {
            return Saml2ResponseValidatorResult.success();
        });

        p.setResponseValidator(responseToken -> {
            Response response = responseToken.getResponse();
            if (response.isSigned()) {
                log.info("response is signed");
            } else {
                log.info("response is not signed, still returning success ");
            }
            return Saml2ResponseValidatorResult.success(); // Example result
        });
        return p;
    }

In OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider there is still one validator:
which is created in createDefaultResponseSignatureValidator(). How can I omit this validation? There is no setter for this like for two other validators.
Ideal solution would be to just receive the SAML response as such and go on from there.
SAML Response is as follows:
<saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                 Destination="xyz"
                 ID="_a17d535d03aa7c955be7c29a17b2b8ee"
                 InResponseTo="ARQdb5ff45-291c-4705-a3e5-b4c4389dc141"
                 IssueInstant="2024-09-20T10:01:08.489Z"
                 Version="2.0"
                 >
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">idp</saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2p:Status xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </saml2p:Status>
    <saml2:EncryptedAssertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                            Id="_284b68747b22dfc831e32effd332e78e"
                            Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
                            >
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                                   Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"
                                   />
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                                   Id="_5020fe474e6a6c387045966595b2bb97"
                                   Recipient="entid1"
                                   >
                    <xenc:EncryptionMethod xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                                           Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"
                                           >
                        <ds:DigestMethod xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
                                         Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"
                                         />
                    </xenc:EncryptionMethod>
                    <ds:KeyInfo>
                        <ds:X509Data>
                            <ds:X509Certificate>public cert</ds:X509Certificate>
                        </ds:X509Data>
                    </ds:KeyInfo>
                    <xenc:CipherData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                        <xenc:CipherValue>encrypted key</xenc:CipherValue>
                    </xenc:CipherData>
                </xenc:EncryptedKey>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
            <xenc:CipherData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <xenc:CipherValue>encrypted msg</xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
        </xenc:EncryptedData>
    </saml2:EncryptedAssertion>
</saml2p:Response>


Ok, it seems the class is designed so that it is not possible. in the OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider there is a final field: private final Converter<ResponseToken, Saml2ResponseValidatorResult> responseSignatureValidator = createDefaultResponseSignatureValidator();
